# Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When the user clicks on the link then toggle function should appear

```
<a href="#" class="play"onclick="toggle()" ><img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/play.png">Watch Trailer</a>
```

the video section is this-

```
<div class="trailer">
  <video src="../MovieLandingPage/video/joker-teaser-1_h1080p.mp4" controls="true"></video>
  <img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/close.png" class="close"onclick="toggle();>
</div>
```

toggle() is defined in javaScript as

```
    function toggle(){
        var trailer = document.querySelector('.trailer');
       // var video = document.querySelector('.video');
        trailer.classList.toggle('active');
        // video.currentTime = 0;
        // video.pause();
    }
```

When I click on the link in the console shows that toggle is not defined **CSS-FILE after clicking this should be executed**

```
.trailer .active{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1 ;
}
```

**EDIT** Snippet of the above

```js
function toggle() {
  var trailer = document.querySelector('.trailer');
  // var video = document.querySelector('.video');
  trailer.classList.toggle('active');
  // video.currentTime = 0;
  // video.pause();
}
```

```css
.trailer .active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="trailer">
  <a href="#" class="play" onclick="toggle()">Watch Trailer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @dgknca is it?  No, it's defined in the jquery namespace or as part of classList

Comment: In CSS, use .trailer.active (no space), if you have space in there, it means “Elements with the class ‘active’ inside an element with class ‘trailer’”.

Comment: 1) converted your code to a snippet - there's no problem other than `document.querySelector('.trailer')` gives null because there's no `.trailer` class.  2) `toggle()` will be called unless it's defined in a different way from how you've presented it, eg is it in a doc.ready?

Comment: see updated code trailer class isthere

Comment: With your edit to include .trailer, the code runs fine.  function `toggle()` is found - it won't be found if it has a different scope, eg inside a doc.ready

Comment: what can i do??

Comment: Use JavaScript to attach your event handlers rather than HTML (e.g., `document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', close);`).

Comment: "*what can I do*" - Update the working snippet to *demonstrate* the problem - as it is, there's no problem *in the question* (obviously there is for you otherwise you wouldn't be asking) so you need to add enough code to the question to reproduce that problem.  See [mcve].

Comment: There is no issue in the snippet you have provided.

Comment: In `<img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/close.png" class="close"onclick="toggle();>`, you're missing a closing quote for the `onclick` attribute. Also, you should really make a habit of separating your attributes by spaces, it makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what happen with my Script tag .why it is showing red color(error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578700/what-happen-with-my-script-tag-why-it-is-showing-red-colorerror)