# what happen with my Script tag .why it is showing red color(error)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image][![][2]][2]

> See Script Tag ..why Script tag and element under Script tag showing red color(error) and when I try to call this function on onClick method it's showing that this function is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing quotation mark on line 33 for `onclick`. Adding it should fix the highlighting issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ending quote in the `onclick` attribute for your `img`.

```
<img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/close.png" class="close" onclick="toggle();"/>
```

Comment: picture of website??

Answer (score 0):

Invalid markup for image below is valid markup

```html
<img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/close.png" class="close" onclick="toggle();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If that image is your current situation, then your function is no longer named `toggle()` but `toggleControls()`.

As for your script tag, you left a space before the closing bracket of the opening tag: `<script >`.
I'm not sure, but changing it to `<script>` might do the trick.

As a side note, in
`<img src="../MovieLandingPage/images/close.png" class="close"onclick="toggle();>`
you're missing a closing quotation mark for the `onclick` attribute.
And you should really make a habit of separating your attributes by spaces, it's a lot more readable.